# How to determine the Redis attack source?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, redis

I am using a Redis Docker image in Kubernetes, everything was working fine with my programs that connect to Redis using both the R client (rredis) and the Python client (redis) until recently when the Redis pod started logging the following error:

```
Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.
```

I found a post that indicated it could be due to the my system's health checks.  How would I determine if that is the case?  How would I determine the origination of the attacks, please?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: no, i think it had something to do with proxy settings...admin fixed it, did not give details.